# Where does drupal determine which theme file to use for an entity field?

Tags: theming, entities

So I've got this problem where file_entity is ignoring the configured video formatter despite triple-checking the GUI configuration. Instead it's being rendered by theme_file_entity_file_video(), which shouldn't be happening.

But it is. So I'm digging back into core to see where the theme function responsible was established. I'm in drupal_render but I'm already seeing the theme function set improperly...

So my question: *Where does drupal determine which theme file/function to use for an entity field?*

*Clarification*: my question is, **"How/where does the theme registry get built for an entity?"** I want to watch it get built with a debugger.

Answer (score 1):

Everything can be overridden by one hook in any module so bear that in mind.

The theme registry is where everything is stored in terms of theming for pages/entities. It all depends on the order here in determining the theme it will use.

You can use the devel module and dpm out the theme registry:

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21theme.inc/function/theme_get_registry/7

It *usually* is built in this order:

1. module where entity is created
2. module where function was called to get the entity
3. your theme directory

but at any point that could have been overridden

Comment: I appreciate this here and I will +1 it, and this did solve my problem, because I consulted the theme registry and found that the theme hooks were not getting applied to my entities after digging. But my question is more "where/how does the theme registry get built for an entity?"